# HttpPostAttribute could not be found. -Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to POST JSON to a controller. I am getting an error in the ajax call to POST. The build is successful. So I tried to Run the Controller action in the interactive and I have the following errors:

```
(1,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(1,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(2,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(3,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GitJSON' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
(3,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GitJSON' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 + additional 1 error
```

I am working on a project using ASP.NET Core Web Application.
This is the JSON I am trying to POST:

> [{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225?v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/8931462?v=4","Name":"aws-microservices-deploy-options","Score":20.521696,"Updatedat":"2018-07-20T12:22:07Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/4046529?v=4","Name":"useful-jenkins-groovy-init-scripts","Score":21.447626,"Updatedat":"2018-07-18T19:52:02Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/6755615?v=4","Name":"dnsjava","Score":34.74705,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T15:16:45Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/504773?v=4","Name":"luke","Score":19.239859,"Updatedat":"2018-06-28T07:27:26Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/536912?v=4","Name":"Wicket-tutorial-examples","Score":37.265644,"Updatedat":"2018-07-14T04:28:50Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/33330803?v=4","Name":"nexus-repository-apt","Score":44.401646,"Updatedat":"2018-07-06T18:28:13Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1321963?v=4","Name":"marc4j","Score":28.282797,"Updatedat":"2018-07-07T15:58:57Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5622390?v=4","Name":"jamonapi","Score":24.564436,"Updatedat":"2018-07-16T07:44:35Z"},{"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}]

I am getting a  400 bad request error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

This is the controller:

```
namespace Github.Controllers
{
    public class Gitcontroller : Controller
    {
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public GitJSON /*async Task<ActionResult>*/ Updateto(GitJSON gitjson)
            {
                return gitjson;
            }
}
```

This is the Model:

```
namespace Github.Models
{
    public class gitd
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarURL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updatedat { get; set; }


    }
    public class GitJSON
    {
        public List<gitd> gitdList { set; get; }
    }
}
```

The namespaces I am using are:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Github.Models;
```

The ajax call URL:

> url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',

Need Help:).

Comment: Does your form contain an anti forgery token?

Comment: you said that build is green, but [`CS0246` error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) is a compilation error. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, I am just starting to learn ASP.NET been a week so dont know much, I am getting:1>------ Build started: Project: Github, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ therefore I assumed Build successful.

Comment: removed, [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], getting the compile error, but the succes function is being executed in the ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please add the [FromBody] before you method parameters, e.g

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public GitJSON /*async Task<ActionResult>*/ Updateto([FromBody]GitJSON gitjson)
            {
                return gitjson;
            }
```

Comment: tried adding [FormBody] - getting the following error:`(3,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FromBodyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have few problems here, but at least one of the steps is to edit your model or JSON that you post.

According to your `GitJSON` model definition, the model binding expects JSON data in the following format:

```
{ 
   gitdList: [
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/7849225? v=4","Name":"simplenlg","Score":22.82041,"Updatedat":"2018-07-21T10:58:33Z"},   
      {"AvatarURL":"https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1123352?v=4","Name":"osgi.enroute","Score":7.6444883,"Updatedat":"2018-07-17T08:26:51Z"}
   ]
}
```

Also, you need to add `[FromBody]` attribute to action parameter to specify that you want to get data from the request body. [MVC doesn't do this by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-formatted-data-from-the-request-body).

Comment: tried adding [FormBody] - getting the following error:`(3,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FromBodyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the gitdList pointer, would have never noticed it, how can I name the array of JSON, sorry complete beginner:)